# How to make the table responsive for mobile width and write the media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

How to make the table responsive for mobile width and write the media queries

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Job Title</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
    <td>David</td>
    <td>Matman</td>
    <td>Programmer Chief Sandwich </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Stefan</td>
    <td>Batman</td>
    <td>Project Manager</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the link for jsfiddle: [LInk](http://jsfiddle.net/jimoscarlobo/muh60k3f/1/)

Comment: _Define_ make the table responsive for mobile width. BTW, did you look at [the article from which this data was (presumably) taken](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/)?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to make table responsive. Use td:nth-of-type(1):before or insert classes.
This is the best example http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of mobile screen sizes:

https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate/wiki/Mobile-Matrices
This should help you on sizing.

Here is a link to a guide for media queries:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/